# Class Self-Reference

Tags: java, class, inheritance, robocode

I have the following code. The angle function needs some information from the class it was called from. What's the best way to do this?

```
class MyScannedRobotEvent extends robocode.ScannedRobotEvent {

    public int angle(robocode.Robot myRobot) {
        return (int) Math.toRadians((myRobot.getHeading() + getBearing()) % 360);
    }
}

public class MyRobot extends robocode.Robot {
int a = MyScannedRobotEvent.angle(*WHATDOIPUTHERE?*);
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Method `angle` is in class `MyScannedRobotEvent`, so you can't invoke it from `MyRobot` the way you have it coded.  Please describe more clearly with a compilable example what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `this`.

```
int a = MyScannedRobotEvent.angle(this);
```

#### See also:

- [Java tutorial - Using the `this` keyword](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Comment: Ah thanks. I'm trying out Java after learning C#/VB .NET. Is this the best way of doing it?

Comment: Depends on the context, which isn't clear from your question. You'll discover it sooner or later though. As far now, that's the only way.

Comment: @Free Bullets: Buddy you should read and practice a lot to be comfortable with Java and to know the best ways.